# Force close when the sd card is removed

Tags: android, sd-card, android-sdcard

My app stores images on the SD card. When the SD card is removed, my app will be forced close. I want to change this, instead of forcing close, I want to put those images on the internal storage when the SD card is removed. Any suggestions?

Edit 1: 
There is no exception in the log. I can see my app is killed when unmount media, but I don't know why.

```
09-19 12:14:33.128: W/ActivityManager(27117): Killing processes unmount media at adjustment 7
09-19 12:14:33.128: W/ActivityManager(27117): Killing ProcessRecord{408f6700 17535:com.google.android.apps.maps/10074} (adj 11): unmount media
09-19 12:14:33.128: W/ActivityManager(27117): Killing ProcessRecord{40a99fd8 28691:cn.wps.livespace/10049} (adj 9): unmount media
```

Comment: is your app installed on the sd-card or can be installed on sd-card? Have you checked AndroidManifest.xml the value of `<manifest android:installLocation` ?

Comment: @k3b I checked the AndroidManifest.xml carefully but did not find that attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if the sd card has already been unmounted when your app starts. Please use the code snippet here and read more info on the android developer site.
[Using the External Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal)

If you want to display images from the internal storage, you should pack these images into you .apk file. Just put them into the /asset folder, and use the [AssetManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html) to read them or even copy them into the internal storage for future usage.

Comment: I've checked the External Storage State when my app starts. My App is not reading or writing the SD card, but it will force close immediately when I remove the SD card. My images are all from the internet,  I just use the SD card as a cache place. See my Edit in the question, maybe help.

Comment: Haven't ever used it, but there is a broadcast android.intent.action.MEDIA_REMOVED that may help.

Comment: @Howard My app will force close immediately when I remove the SD card, so I don't have the chance to receive the broadcast and do the proper operation.

Comment: Is the file left open even if you are not reading or writing? If so, try a check availability/open where indicated/store image/close cycle. I am guessing that if the file is not connected to your app at removal the app wouldn't force close.

Comment: Yeah, I have a file left open, I think this is the problem.

Comment: @LeiGuo did you find the solution to this problem? because I am also having same problem. If the problem was file left open then how did you close it? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

```
File temp;
if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
temp =new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"ImageFile");
else
temp=ctx.getCacheDir();
```

Call every time when reading and writing data...

Comment: I'm not reading or writing data when my app force close. I open the app for a long time, so the reading or writing must finish, but my app will force close immediately when I remove the SD card.